# Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity on Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I am creating a Xamarin.Android app on Visual Studio 2017, and am unable to load any activity other than `MainActivity` that is generated when starting the app.

I have created a new activity, and if I try to set it as the main launcher, during debugging I get this error: `Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo`before the app manages to load.

This is my Activity code:

```
using...
namespace myApp
    {
        [Activity(Label = "Pick your instrument", MainLauncher = true)]
        public class InstrumentsActivity : Activity
        {
            protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
                RequestWindowFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
                base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
                SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Instruments);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When changing the `MainLauncher` Activity, perform a clean/rebuild of the solution/project (delete the apk from the device if still having a problem and do a clean/rebuild all again)

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot @SushiHangover!